# Slicing numpy array with another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I've got a large one-dimensional array of integers I need to take slices off. That's trivial, I'd just do `a[start:end]`. The problem is that I need more of these slices. `a[start:end]` does not work if start and end are arrays. For loop could be used for this, but I need it to be as fast as possible (it is a bottleneck), so a native numpy solution would be welcome.

To further illustrate, I have this:

```
a = numpy.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], numpy.int16)
start = numpy.array([1, 5, 7], numpy.int16)
end   = numpy.array([2, 10, 9], numpy.int16)
```

And need to somehow make it into this:

```
[[1], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [7, 8]]
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what `start` and `end` have to do with this.  As an aside though, I don't think you'll be able to do this entirely in numpy as numpy arrays need to be rectangular.

Comment: YOu might try making the start-end values as tuples in a list.

Comment: As there seems no canonical numpy solution here, if you need more ideas, you might want to maybe add what you actually do with it afterwards and if the slices have some special properties.

Answer (score 9):

This can (almost?) be done in pure `numpy` using masked arrays and stride tricks. First, we create our mask:

```
>>> indices = numpy.arange(a.size)
>>> mask = ~((indices >= start[:,None]) & (indices < end[:,None]))
```

Or more simply:

```
>>> mask = (indices < start[:,None]) | (indices >= end[:,None])
```

The mask is `False` (i.e. values not masked) for those indices that are `>=` to the start value and `<` the end value. (Slicing with `None` (aka `numpy.newaxis`) adds a new dimension, enabling broadcasting.) Now our mask looks like this:

```
>>> mask
array([[ True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
         True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False,
        False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False,
         True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Now we have to stretch the array to fit the mask using `stride_tricks`:

```
>>> as_strided = numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided
>>> strided = as_strided(a, mask.shape, (0, a.strides[0]))
>>> strided
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11]], dtype=int16)
```

This looks like a 3x12 array, but each row points at the same memory. Now we can combine them into a masked array:

```
>>> numpy.ma.array(strided, mask=mask)
masked_array(data =
 [[-- 1 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- -- -- 5 6 7 8 9 -- --]
 [-- -- -- -- -- -- -- 7 8 -- -- --]],
             mask =
 [[ True False  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True False False False False False  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True False False  True  True  True]],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

This isn't quite the same as what you asked for, but it should behave similarly.

Comment: Cool idea, would be interesting to know if this approach works for his usecase (on newer numpy versions). The current one lacks the `where` keyword to `ufunc`s (1.7 will not have it for reductions too). Which means that your stride tricks array will by copied into the full version, for almost anything you do on it...

Comment: Mmh, the lack of `where` in `ufunc` has *nothing* to do with the problem at hand, and `np.ma` usually avoids copies... It's not really a matter of using `np.ma` (cool idea in itself) that bothers me, it's that it probably won't beat constructing slides with a loop or list comprehension (just because of doubling the array size)... Still, it's fun, +1

Comment: @PierreGM, yeah, I kind of only thought of reduction functions there, but at some point those are likely to be wanted...

Answer (score 6):

There is no numpy method to do this. Note that since it is irregular, it would only be a list of arrays/slices anyways. However I would like to add that for all (binary) `ufuncs` which are almost all functions in numpy (or they are at least based on them), there is the `reduceat` method, which might help you to avoid actually creating a list of slices, and thus, if the slices are small, speed up calculations too:

```
In [1]: a = np.arange(10)

In [2]: np.add.reduceat(a, [0,4,7]) # add up 0:4, 4:7 and 7:end
Out[2]: array([ 6, 15, 24])

In [3]: np.maximum.reduceat(a, [0,4,7]) # maximum of each of those slices
Out[3]: array([3, 6, 9])

In [4]: w = np.asarray([0,4,7,10]) # 10 for the total length

In [5]: np.add.reduceat(a, w[:-1]).astype(float)/np.diff(w) # equivalent to mean
Out[5]: array([ 1.5,  5. ,  8. ])
```

EDIT: Since your slices overlap, I will add that this is OK too:

```
# I assume that start is sorted for performance reasons.
reductions = np.column_stack((start, end)).ravel()
sums = np.add.reduceat(a, reductions)[::2]
```

The `[::2]` should be no big deal here normally, since no real extra work is done for overlapping slices.

Also there is one problem here with slices for which `stop==len(a)`. This must be avoided. If you have exactly one slice with it, you could just do `reductions = reductions[:-1]` (if its the last one), but otherwise you will simply need to append a value to `a` to trick `reduceat`:

```
 a = np.concatenate((a, [0]))
```

As adding one value to the end does not matter since you work on the slices anyways.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a "pure" numpy solution (although as @mgilson's comment notes, it's hard to see how the irregular output could be a numpy array), but:

```
a = numpy.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], numpy.int16)
start = numpy.array([1, 5, 7], numpy.int16)
end   = numpy.array([2, 10, 9], numpy.int16)

map(lambda range: a[range[0]:range[1]],zip(start,end))
```

gets you:

```
[array([1], dtype=int16), array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=int16),  array([7, 8], dtype=int16)]
```

as required.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it in one line, it would be:

```
x=[list(a[s:e]) for (s,e) in zip(start,end)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar solution like timday. Similar speed:

```
a = np.random.randint(0,20,1e6)
start = np.random.randint(0,20,1e4)
end = np.random.randint(0,20,1e4)

def my_fun(arr,start,end):
        return arr[start:end]

%timeit [my_fun(a,i[0],i[1]) for i in zip(start,end)]
%timeit map(lambda range: a[range[0]:range[1]],zip(start,end))
```

`100 loops, best of 3: 7.06 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 6.87 ms per loop`