# How can I define multiple slices of a numpy array based on pairs of start/end indices without iterating?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of integers.

I have two other arrays representing the start and length (or it could be start and end) indices into this array that identify sequences of integers that I need to process. The sequences are variable length.

```
x=numpy.array([2,3,5,7,9,12,15,21,27,101, 250]) #Can have length of millions

starts=numpy.array([2,7]) # Can have lengths of thousands
ends=numpy.array([5,9])

# required output is x[2:5],x[7:9] in flat 1D array 
# [5,7,9,12,21,27,101]
```

I can do this easily with for loops but the application is performance sensitive so I'm looking for a way to do it without Python iteration.

Any help will be gratefully received!

Doug

Comment: Could there be overlaps? As in `x[2:5],x[3:9]` etc? If so, would be the overlaps be included as many times as they occur?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589923/slicing-numpy-array-with-another-array

Comment: No overlaps are possible

Comment: @scotsman60 So, would the expected output be `x[2:5] + x[3:9]` or `x[2:5] + x[5:9]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

One vectorized approach would be with masking created off with broadcasting -

```
In [16]: r = np.arange(len(x))

In [18]: x[((r>=starts[:,None]) & (r<ends[:,None])).any(0)]
Out[18]: array([ 5,  7,  9, 21, 27])
```

**Approach #2**

Another vectorized way would be with creating ramps of 1s and 0s with cumsum (should be better with many start-end pairs), like so -

```
idx = np.zeros(len(x),dtype=int)
idx[starts] = 1
idx[ends[ends<len(x)]] = -1
out = x[idx.cumsum().astype(bool)]
```

**Approach #3**

Another loop-based one to achieve memory-efficiency, could be better with many entries in `starts,ends` pairs -

```
mask = np.zeros(len(x),dtype=bool)
for (i,j) in zip(starts,ends):
    mask[i:j] = True
out = x[mask]
```

**Approach #4**

For completeness, here's another with loop to select slices and then assign into an initialized array and should be good on slices to be selected off a large array -

```
lens = ends-starts
out = np.empty(lens.sum(),dtype=x.dtype)
start = 0
for (i,j,l) in zip(starts,ends,lens):
    out[start:start+l] = x[i:j]
    start += l
```

If the iterations are a lot, there's a minor optimization possible to reduce compute per iteration -

```
lens = ends-starts
lims = np.r_[0,lens].cumsum()
out = np.empty(lims[-1],dtype=x.dtype)
for (i,j,s,t) in zip(starts,ends,lims[:-1],lims[1:]):
    out[s:t] = x[i:j]
```

Comment: Thanks @Divakar!!! The first solution is exactly what I was looking for. I can conditionally switch to one of the others if I run short of memory but - but if I run short of memory on this operation I have bigger problems elsewhere in my application....